# inserting all entries stored in an array (for statement)

Tags: php, mysql

I have all of my keys stored in the array $addkeys (the total amount of keys always changes). The **var_dump($addkeys)** outputs:

```
Arrayarray(9) { [0]=> string(17) "11111-11111-11111" [1]=> string(17) "22222-22222-22222" [2]=> string(17) "33333-33333-33333" [3]=> string(17) "44444-44444-44444" [4]=> string(17) "55555-55555-55555" [5]=> string(17) "66666-66666-66666" [6]=> string(17) "77777-77777-77777" [7]=> string(17) "88888-88888-88888" [8]=> string(17) "99999-99999-99999" }
```

I want to insert each of them into the database if they don't already exist. I understand how to check for a single existing key in a string and do an INSERT if it doesn't already exist, but the incremental loop confuses me. Any help would be appreciated. I understand people might recommend using PDO for the mysql queries, but please disregard.

**My code:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($addkeys); $i++) {

// check each key in $addkeys to see if it exists already in the database to prevent a duplicate entry

$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code = '$addkeys'")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
$addkeys = $row[0];

if(!isset($addkeys)) {
// entry doesn't exist insert the key
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO codes (code, title) VALUES ('$addkeys', 'sample title')")
or die(mysql_error());

}
}
```

Comment: is `code` a `keyed` column in the db?

Comment: You don't need to check first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `mysql_num_rows` to check data already store in your database or not. and you are use direct array `addkeys` in your query you have to use it like `addkeys[$i]`

Your code would be

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($addkeys); $i++) {

// check each key in $addkeys to see if it exists already in the database to prevent a duplicate entry

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code = '$addkeys[$i]]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($rows < 1) {
// entry doesn't exist insert the key
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO codes (code, title) VALUES ('$addkeys[$i]]', 'sample title')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

> Note:- mysql is depricated instead use mysqli OR PDO

Comment: Thanks. I really need to learn more about loops. Do you have a resource I could read?

Comment: Could that be made into a single SQL query?  Like "insert into codes (code,title) values('$addkeys[$i]], 'sample title') where (select code from codes where code ='$addkeys[$i]) = 0" ???

Comment: What if someone inserts a key while you're checking? And never execute a query inside a loop.

Comment: That is more likely to happen with TWO SQL queries than one. Usually a database will auto-lock a record when it gets an action on it.  But the example given allows the database to unlock the record after the SELECT and before the INSERT.

Comment: @MarkManning have you check the syntax of query  that you have suggeted!!

Comment: @Saty - That is why I said "Could that..." and "Like..." because I am unsure of the exact syntax or if I got it right.  I'm good at SQL - but I always check what I do to ensure it is right when >I< use it.  Here I am saying could this be done?  Or Could the two commands be combined? And the question was directed at you.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a keyed column you could use the `on duplicate key update` syntax

```
<?php
    foreach( $addkeys as $key ){
        $title='sample title';

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO codes (`code`, `title`) VALUES ('{$key}', '{$title}')
            on duplicate key update `code`={$key}, `title`='{$title}'");    
    }
?>
```